# XAMPP OCI will not enable despite all options

Tags: php, xampp, oracle12c, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, instantclient

To mimic my university's set up on my personal PC, I am using oracle 12c Database, XAMPP  7.1.12. and Instantclient 12.2.

my database 12c is confirmed working (can use SQLPlus to create db etc). My XAMPP server is reachable when running and phpinfo is available. (my XAMPP is x86 architecture and the relevant oracle instantclient is to match)

I have followed these exacts step yet phpinfo does not show OCI8 section.(I have gotten it to work successfully yesterday on a friends laptop following these exact steps but I'm not sure what steps I'm missing this time.)

1. added instantclient to PATH environment variable
2. edited php.ini to remove the ; from `extension=oci8_12c`
3. made sure the correct DLLs were available in `..\XAMPP\php\ext`

as an additional troubleshoot step.

4. added the instantclient 9 oci DLLs to `..\XAMPP\php\` and `..\XAMPP\apache\bin`

after restarting the XAMPP apache server, looking at phpinfo there is no OCI8 section.

or is there another localhost server I can use to test my php site's connection to my OracleDB using OCI

This is the guide I originally followed which worked on one PC but not the other
[XAMPP OCI Tutorial](https://odan.github.io/2017/03/21/xampp-oracle-driver-setup-v12.html)

Comment: Try to run `cd /path/to/oci_package; phpize; ./configure -with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/lib;make install;export PHP_DTRACE=yes;`

Comment: @ArpitJain is that the WINDOWS.X64_12200_db_home folder before phpize? oracle is new to me, and the path to instantclient 12.2?

Comment: On window, you may want to follow these instructions: https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php. I haven't tried this yet my own just trying to helping you out.

Comment: [Installing XAMPP on Windows for PHP and Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/installing-xampp-on-windows-for-php-and-oracle-database) may have some useful tips.